# How to check where my PATH is modified?

Tags: ubuntu, path, bashrc, .bash-profile

I have in my PATH a folder destination included which does not exist any more. Still I just can't find in which file is it set. I checked for .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile does not exist.

Is there an easy method to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in `/etc/profile.d/` check all files in that folder.

Comment: I did not find the destination included there, so overrided it in .profie then went `source ~/.profile` command. Maybe that was the problem. Still thanks, good to know now.

Answer (score 0):

Run `bash --login -v`, will print all the scripts executed from bash startups. The file name will be like `# filename` at top of the commands.

Comment: Is there a `zsh` equivalent to this?